# Issues with version management in maven

Tags: java, maven, version-control

**The problem I encountered is this, here is the definition in my POM file**.\

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

In this dependency, It's having a sub-dependency which is starter-tomcat

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But In my maven tree

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.3.6.RELEASE:compile
```

By the way this project have a **parent**, In parent There is a 2.3.6 starter-webdependency.

I want to know **why the sub-dependency starter-tomcat in the web-starter I referenced 2.0.0 is not the 2.0.0 I see, but 2.3.6 in the parent dependency**.

Comment: My first guess was, that it is inherited, because of what the maven tree shows. But `spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE`'s pom.xml clearly references 2.0.0.RELEASE of the tomcat dependency. Did you reimported the dependencies? Do you have multiple pom.xmls in your project?

Comment: Please post your full pom file otherwise it's just guessing what's wrong..furthermore why using such an old spring boot version which is not supported anymore ...

Comment: Hi @ValerijDobler,In this project, just have only one pom.xml, and i didn't reimport any dependencies about tomcat, so i am very confuse about the sub-dependency'version.

Comment: @khmarbaise bro, it's too much another dependencies, but I promise that I don't find any dependencies about tomcat. By the way, this version is the version the company used before

Comment: I guess you have another dependency in your project which uses it.. The version is different because another dependency pulls it in...without more informations or coming via the parent as you mentioned..but without the full pom its not possible to say...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I know it. But the higher version is in this project's parent definition. Is that parent's version-control can override this project's definition?
``` xml
 <!-- Project dependencies -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Ah now that's the reason..because you are manually defining versions in your dependencies.. In a spring boot project you define the version of the dependencies via the parent (which uses spring-boot-dependencies) where all dependencies defined with their appropriate versions... and that's the reason. Furthermore a good reason why using an older version? Current spring boot 2.6.7 ...

Comment: @khmarbaise, This project is very old, if update spring-boot version , this could affect a lot of business. I just want to know, will the version defined in my current pom file be overwritten by the version defined by the parent project?

Comment: But using such old stuff means very likely having security issues ... using old software is always dangerous...

Comment: I know, I will report the low version to the superior later, but this is not the main question I want to ask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
There are two ways to solve this question

1. exclude your sub-dependency and add a new version dependency.
2. use  to control this denpendency